# How to set full table width on landscape document with iTextSharp XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml in C# ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: itext, landscape, xmlworker

I am working with ASP.NET MVC and I am using iTextSharp to render an HTML page to PDF, in detail iTextSharp XMLWorkerHelper tool.
It works fine with all the pages I have to parse and render into PDF when they have a portrait orientation, but **it fails when they have a landscape** one.

Here is a very simple sample of the HTML I would like to render in landscape:

```
<table style="border:1px solid red; width:280mm;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            In this cell there is a content that can be very large...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the table width should be of 280mm (a little less than the full A4 width in landscape mode).

And here is the core of the HTML to PDF conversion:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    IView viewEngineResult;
    ViewContext viewContext;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewName))
        ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    context.Controller.ViewData.Model = Model;

    var workStream = new MemoryStream();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(842f, 595f));
    document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

    TextWriter tr = new StringWriter(sb);
    viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, ViewName, null).View;
    viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewEngineResult,       context.Controller.ViewData,
    context.Controller.TempData, tr);
    viewEngineResult.Render(viewContext, tr);

    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false; 

    document.Open();    
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, stream, (Stream)null);
    document.Close();

    new FileContentResult(workStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf").ExecuteResult(context);
}
```

The result is a landscape document, with a table with a red border, but with a wrong width. It's easy to understand that **the rendered width**, on the PDF, **is** not 280mm, but **the max width the table may have on a portrait A4 document**.

I tried different ways:

- I created a PdfPTable, setting to 100% its width. Then I created a PdfPCell inside the table. Finally I put the ParseXHtml result in that cell. The result was a full "A4 landscape width" cell, with my 280mm red border table inside, but with the usual wrong width (the max of a portrait A4 document)
- I tried to insert document.NewPage() before to execute ParseXHtml, because I found on different posts that a "NewPage" invoke is needed due to let the document have right dimensions...but no good results also from this operation.

Maybe I am trying to follow wrong ways, and there is a very simple and stupid way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

***UPDATED***

I tried to solve out this problema with a workaround.
Between the `document.Open()` and the `document.Close()` methods I substituted the:
`XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, stream, (Stream)null);`

with the following one:

```
var handler = new SampleHandler();
using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
{
   //Parse
   XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(handler , sr);
}
foreach (var element in handler.elements)
{
   document.Add(element);
}
```

I created a new class:

```
public class SampleHandler : IElementHandler
{
   public List<IElement> elements = new List<IElement>();

   public void Add(IWritable w)
   {
      if (w is WritableElement)
      {
         // Here all the logic useful to catch the PDFPTable and redefine
         // its width or other tricks (such as nested tables redefining)
      }
   }
}
```

As I mentioned with the very first issue, I don't know if there is a more simple way to do it. And to be honest, eve if it works, I don't know if this workaround is good or not...

Comment: I've just put an ***UPDATE*** to the post: a simple workaround I found myself with some comments from different blogs. I seems to work, but it is just a "workaround"...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<style>
table,th,td{
width:100%; //your width here
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a functional solution using the code you suggested in your UPDATE ??

I have the same problem and I have done some tests and found that the result of sb.ToString () is an Html that contains all the necessary tags for the correct table formation using the full width in landscape.

```
public string RenderRazorView(ControllerContext context, string viewName)
    {
        IView viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewName, null).View;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();


        using (TextWriter tr = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewEngineResult, context.Controller.ViewData,
                context.Controller.TempData, tr);
            viewEngineResult.Render(viewContext, tr);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

So I understand that all the unwanted changes happen in XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance (). ParseXHtml 
So your code is intended to make changes that are already made and will not change the Parser result.

Comment: Neumann, do you here try to actually *answer* the question? Or is this merely a "I have this problem, too" comment?

Comment: I just tried to explain why the workaround provided by Flavio M. does not seem to work.